# flask form current_user NoneType

Tags: python, flask, nonetype

The code below is found in [my project](https://github.com/alex-re/flask_project2):

```
flaskblog/ 
    /users 
        /forms.py 
            class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
```

---

```
## ERROR ##

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

but it should have current_user:

```
User('test1', 'test1@test.com', 'fdd6f1e03J3fc6a4.jpg')
```

error content:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flaskblog import app
  File "/home/ali/flask/flask_project2/Flask_Blog/flaskblog/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from flaskblog import routes  # here because preventional of circular import.
  File "/home/ali/flask/flask_project2/Flask_Blog/flaskblog/routes.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flaskblog.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, UpdateAccountForm
  File "/home/ali/flask/flask_project2/Flask_Blog/flaskblog/forms.py", line 40, in <module>
    class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
  File "/home/ali/flask/flask_project2/Flask_Blog/flaskblog/forms.py", line 43, in UpdateAccountForm
    render_kw={"value":current_user.username.data})
  File "/home/ali/flask/flask_project2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'
```

### USERS/forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError, Optional
from flaskblog.models import User
from flask_login import current_user


class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username',
                            validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)],
                            render_kw={"value":current_user.username.data})
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
    def validate_username(self, username):
        if username.data != current_user.username:
            user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
            if user:
                raise ValidationError('That username is taken. Please choose a different one.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if email.data != current_user.email:
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
            if user:
                raise ValidationError('That email is taken. Please choose a different one.')
```

---

### FLASKBLOG/models.py

```
 # models.py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.png')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)  # we will hash passwords
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)  # upper case because it hints to a "class"

    def get_reset_token(self, expires_sec=1800):
        s = Serializer(current_app.secret_key, expires_sec)
        # s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        return s.dumps({'user_id' : self.id}).decode('utf-8')  # generats token
```

excuse me if i had mistakes in english :)

Comment: Well, it seems like current_user == None. So maybe show us what's going on in flask_login?

Comment: First, as the error explcity says: 'NoneType' object has no attribute means that there isn't any 'user' in 'current_user' because is indeed None. So i think the real error is not in your file called 'forms.py' but rather somewhere else (unless 'current_user.username.data' is correct) You need to add more code in order to understand why 'current user' is none. .

Comment: if I sayed to```"value":current_user``` it works it prints that user object but if i sayed ```value":str(current_user) it will rerurn NoneType

Comment: excuse me  Bastien Harkins I cant understand what part of my code you want

Comment: I added my github link

Comment: If I have time today i try to debug it. I starred your Github repo ;)

Comment: I clone the code and I try to reproduce the error but I can't...Did you fix it or what? If not can you tell me what action you take to encounter the error?

Comment: Also, if you still have error. update the error massage because it looks like you update the code..in the error I can see : /flask_project2/Flask_Blog/flaskblog/routes.py. but there is not routes.py under flaskblog, the routes.py are below other directory (example users) so the code changed

Comment: I could upload the picture successsfullly without changing anything on your code